# Hiding buttons on an infopath printout

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, forms-services

Just curious whether there is a way to hide buttons/other elements on an infopath 2010 form so that that don't appear on the print preview/ printout.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tia,

A similar questions is asked [on this forum](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/5110/48824.aspx)

Please see Clay's answer, posted below:

> In order to get the print out you want you need to create one more
>   view specifically for the print out.  So you would format it to show
>   the elements from all of your views and process and format it the way
>   you needed.  InfoPath has some limitations when creating paper forms,
>   I believe since the whole point is having the form and information
>   electronic, but you should be able to get what you need for this.  You
>   can also go into the print properties for each view and set your new
>   print view as the default. That way whereever they are when they print
>   they get the correct, complete format.

So as he said, create a read-only view and set it as default in Print Properties!

I hope this helps